# Обмен данными между клиентом и сервером

Tags: android, клиент-сервер

Небольшой чат написан под Windows,он работает посредством скачивания и закачивания клиентом текстового файла с сервера и на сервер соответственно (с некоторым интервалом). Мне хотелось бы перенести данный проект на Android. Но из-за сути работы чата, я боюсь, что программа израсходует весь трафик. Возможны ли альтернативные способы для обмена информации в данном случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Закачивание текстового файла само по себе не является чем-то плохим. Протокол HTTP по природе своей передает текстовые файлы, только это никому не мешает настолько, что об этом все давно забыли. Важно лишь, сколько лишней информации приходится передавать. Проанализируйте и оптимизируйте при необходимости.

Если бы была возможность выбирать, я бы сделал так: при активной работе приложение оставляет открытой коннекцию с сервером. В коннекции какой-нибудь ориентированный на события протокол, например, WebSocket. Если приложение уходит в фон, то оно рвет коннекцию. Сервер, обнаружив, что конекции с клиентом нет, новые сообщения отправляет с помощью Firebase Cloud Messages (в народе называемые "пушами"). Приложение, получив "пуш", показывает нотификацию. Пользователь может кликнуть нотификацию, тогда приложение откроется и опять установит собственное соединение с сервером.